# How do I enable Bluetooth in my Nikon D3400?

Tags: nikon-d3400, snapbridge, bluetooth

The option to turn on Bluetooth (and location) in my Nikon D3400 is greyed out, and an error pops up that says, "this option is not available at current settings or in the camera's current state".

I have searched the manuals and there is nothing about enabling Bluetooth. How do I turn it on?

Comment: Note that the question in the suggested duplicate refers to a Nikon D5600 rather than D3400, but the advice and resolution is the same: you have to use your phone's Snapbridge app to initiate/control the connection.